# HTTP POST Parameter as Query String in Url

Tags: string, http, url, post, parameters

does anyone know if it is possible to store key-value-pairs in the URL given in a POST-Request (as query-string - for example https://example.com?one=two&two=three). I know the parameters are usually stored in the body with POST, but I specifically need them as part of the URL. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it in practice.  What web servers support, it I can't say.

One thing to consider, though: don't put sensitive details in URL parameters, as anyone behind a proxy might well find that information logged (though frankly, the normal POST parameters could be logged as well; it's just not common).  Encrypt sensitive details, and note that HTTPS is not enough for those behind an enterprise proxy and subject to DLP protections.

Comment: P.S. I imagine you'd be stuck using JavaScript to populate URL parameters for a POST, as I'm pretty sure there isn't an HTML option for that.  But, it does raise question: are there web servers that would support a combination of both, or would that require some special coding on the server side?

Answer (score -1):

share some code.  What have you tried?  Where did you fail? We wanna see where you got stuck in your method/logic or approach.  And the link you provided does not give us any data - Your post need more clarification/information.  Good luck with the search

Comment: POST /muster.html?Name=Max+Mustermann&Ort=Musterstadt&PLZ=12345 HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/3.0
Accept: image/jpeg, */*
Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Connection: close

Comment: I don't have code per so, just want to know if it is valid to send the query parameters as part of the first line in the HTTP-Post request.